# When I try to install cython I get an error message unable to execute gcc-4.0

Tags: python, macos, gcc, cython, kivy

I have scowered stack overflow all day today trying to figure out why when I try to install cython

`unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1`

I am using OSX mountain lion and I am using default python with pygame and easygui and command line tools installed trying to make my first app using kivy and I need cython to make the gui.. Are there any other things I should use instead of Kivy but I am pretty impressed from what I saw online. If anyone has any other tips on installing Kivy? I am very lost doing this sorry for a trivial question!

Comment: do you want to compile Cython? Is your platform 64 bit?

Comment: install cythin onto my mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which python are you using, the system python or macports or something else?

Make sure you have XCode and gcc installed on your system first.  Running `which gcc` on the command line will help identify where your current version of gcc resides.  I assume you already checked this?

As an alternative, you can try installing a precompiled version of `cython` such as the one that comes with anaconda or the enthought python distribution.

Unfortunately, there's not enough information here to give a definitive answer.....